# Javascript cookie to hide alert box

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cookies, alert

Ok I looked all over the internet but I just can't find what I want:

I have a page that sends a javascript alert to iPhone/android users only, and give them the option to go to the mobile website (if they click cancel another alert box shows up telling them how to acces the mobile site anyway).

But, this is very annoying if you go to that website everytime, and you everytime have to click cancel (this is only annoying to the people who click cancel all the time), so, can I get a cookie that remembers you clicked cancel and won't show the popup again for e.g. a month?

I don't want it to remember the choice (maybe users who clicked agree want to switch back but automatically get redirected again) but just not to show the confirm box anymore...

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just detect the user agent string and put a banner in the page advertising the mobile page.  Pop ups are almost **never** a good idea.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Try using a cookie library like cookie.js or jquery-cookie plugin to read and set the values. http://code.google.com/p/cookie-js/source/browse/trunk/cookie.js

Comment: Agree with slayton, those boxes are annoying even on the first visit. Good practice is to redirect them to your mobile site if the user agent string dictates so, and provide a way for them to go to the desktop site (a link, preferably one that turns off mobile for the session).